# Forcing a terminal operation

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type, java-9

I have a visitor that returns a generic type to provide flexibility in use:

```
interface Base {
    default <T> Stream<T> accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this).stream();
    }
}

class Sub implements Base {
    <T> Stream<T> accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return Stream.concat(super.accept(visitor), visitor.visit(this).stream());
    }
}

interface Visitor<T> {
    default Optional<T> visit(Base base) { 
        return Optional.empty() 
    }

    default Optional<T> visit(Sub sub){ 
        return Optional.empty() 
    }
}
```

I have created a method that visits a stream of objects:

```
<T> Stream<T> visitAll(Visitor<T> visitor) {
    return getStream().flatMap(o -> o.accept(visitor));
}
```

This work perfectly when the visitor is returning a value:

```
visitAll(new Visitor<Sub>() {
    Optional<Sub> visit(Sub sub) {
        return Optional.of(sub);
    }
}).forEach(...);
```

The problem comes when this is used with a visitor that doesn't return a value:

```
visitAll(new Visitor<Void>() {
    Optional<Void> visit(Sub sub) {
        // do something with sub
        return Optional.empty();
    }
});
```

In this case the stream doesn't terminate so the visits never occur.

A possible solution is to force a terminal operation:

```
<T> Stream<T> visitAll(Visitor<T> visitor) {
    return getStream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
        .flatMap(o -> o.accept(visitor));
}
```

Another solution is to always use the value:

```
visitAll(new Visitor<Void>() {
    Optional<Void> visit(Sub sub) {
        // do something with sub
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}).findAny();
```

Is there a more elegant way to force a terminal operation on a stream? Or is there an alternate design you can suggest that avoids the issue?

Comment: I think it's a mistake to have `visit()` return a stream in the first place. It violates the expectation that the visitor necessarily visits the object. Return a list and let the client stream that if they want.

Comment: @shmosel that's a good suggestion - thanks. My only concern is that there will be lots of list objects created on the way through. Though I guess I shouldn't assume that's any worse than all the streams created in this solution! I will give that a go though also interested to see if there are any other suggestions put forward.

Comment: `visitor.visit(this)` returns `Optional<T>`, would you tell me how do you make `Stream<T>` from the `Optional<T>`? `visitor.visit(this).stream();` is erroneous.

Comment: @Nikolas Optional has a stream method as of JDK9. see the [Optional<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) class

Comment: @Aominè: Okay, I am not knowledgeable of [tag:Java-9]. I add the tag.

Comment: I don’t understand the problem. The caller may chain a terminal operation which short-circuits or chain no terminal operation at all and will get what they ask for. In ordinary applications of the visitor pattern, i.e for traversing a tree or other structure, there is no requirement to traverse all nodes either. Usually this is made explicit, either by a returning value indicating whether to continue or by having to manually call a “dive in” method. The former is not so different from your `Optional`/`findAny` combination.

Answer (score 0):

I would make two versions of `visitAll`, one that returns a stream and one that terminates the stream and returns nothing.

```
<T> Stream<T> visitAllStream(Visitor<T> visitor) {
    return getStream().flatMap(o -> o.accept(visitor));
}

void visitAll(Visitor<?> visitor) {
    getStream().forEach(o -> o.accept(visitor));
}
```

This way you would only use `visitAllStream` when you're going to do further operations on the results. You'd still have to make sure you don't use `visitAllStream` when it should be `visitAll`, but it would make mistakes more obvious.